# FRP example with event loop or thread pool

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, nonblocking, frp, event-loop

My question is ultimately for ruby rx library, although any example in any language would be gladly appreciated.
Basically what I want is to schedule every operation to an existing event loop (or thread pool, for that matter). I guess this has to be done by a scheduler. I haven't found any example of a scheduler sending the recursive operations to an event loop, and this is why I'm asking. Here's the list for ruby rx:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxRuby/tree/master/lib/rx/concurrency

Why the event loop? Because I want to add IO operations which work inside the event loop and leverage concurrency. Something like this:

```
Rx::Observable.from_enumerable(hosts).
  map { |h| HTTP.connect(h) }.
  map{|host| host.get("http://myservice/somelist.txt") }.
  on_next { |html| parse(html).each_line.....} # you get the idea
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normally done with a Scheduler, and I would expect that the RubyRx port has included the `EventloopScheduler`.

You can either enqueue/scheduler them onto it with an `ObserveOn` operator

```
Rx::Observable.from_enumerable(hosts).
  observeOn(els). # you have declared els somewhere else as an EventLoopScheduler instance
  map { |h| HTTP.connect(h) }.
  map{|host| host.get("http://myservice/somelist.txt") }.
  on_next { |html| parse(html).each_line.....} # you get the idea
```

or you could add the concurrency in the map

```
Rx::Observable.from_enumerable(hosts).
  observeOn(els). # you have declared els somewhere else as an EventLoopScheduler instance
  map { |h| HTTP.connect(h) }.
  flatmap{|host| Rx::Observable.start(host.get("http://myservice/somelist.txt"), els) }.
  on_next { |html| parse(html).each_line.....} # you get the idea
```

I hope that code could work (I am C#/JS)

Comment: it's exactly the definition of the scheduler that I'm missing, as the examples I see have a lot of callbacks I'm kinda allowed to overwrite (#schedule_relative, #schedule_recursive, #schedule_recursive_with_state...) and it's those interactions I'm fighting to understand. Do you know examples available (maybe in C# or JS)?

Comment: I wrote some stuff on Schedulers for C# here -http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html. It appears that the EventLoopScheduler is missing from RxRuby. This could be an opportunity for you to create a PR and contribute it back.

Comment: not only that, a thread pool scheduler seems to be also missing. will have a look at it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: In .NET the ThreadPool is built into the framework. So if Ruby has a ThreadPool too, then yes it is missing, else, Rx would need to build a threadpool implementation and then also provider the scheduler to target that.

Comment: There's a fundamental flaw in the whole process: the line: ```map { |h| HTTP.connect(h) }.``` must be executed within the specialized loop. ```observe_on``` only schedules the observers (the on_next callback there), but not the operators. How can I operate on all? is the C# implementation fundamentally sequential as well?

Comment: ok, wasn't really about that... still, simply overwriting the callback and scheduling ```schedule_recursive_with_state``` to the event pool won't do what's expected, as it will process messages sequentially.

Comment: TBH It is hard to know exactly what you are are after. I am not sure what an _event pool_ is. Rx and EventLoopSchedulers are both designed to process sequences of data, well sequentially. Maybe you want to execute the `Http.connect(h)` in an async manner and allow for out of ordering? If so then you probably want to `.FlatMap(h=>Observable.Start(()=>h.Connect(), els))`

Comment: sorry, pool -> loop, caught in the mental anagram. yes, that's exactly what I want, not "connecting" sequentially, but out-of-ordering them all, a la non-blocking interleaving.

Comment: LOL I see. Happens to us all. Then in this case, I dont think you do want and EventLoopScheduler. As I understand them an EventLoop or a message dispatcher is a single threaded (while) loop. Issuing messages to it, will unblock your current thread by en-queuing work for the EventLoop to do it when it gets to it. So in your case I think you want to use a ThreadPoolScheduler or something else that allows not just asynchrony but concurrency.

Comment: Further more as Rx is designed to be sequential with in a sequence, I think you will need to consider nested-observables see : http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html. This is effectively what the `Observable.Start` in the `flatMap`/`SelectMany` is allowing.